# How do I transfer this SELECT statement into a DELETE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *, 
             ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER (
                  PARTITION BY ResidentID, PostedON, PayerTypeID    
                  ORDER BY StatementNumber
                  ) seq
    FROM Statements
    ) s
        INNER JOIN person p ON s.ResidentID = p.ID
WHERE seq > 1
AND p.FacilityID = 275
ORDER BY s.ResidentID
```

Having a pickle of a time translating this into a DELETE. Anybody got an idea as to why?

Here is the original problem:

Ok, so a flaw in my code created a bunch of duplicate statements for the same charge. They have the same ResidentID and same PostedOn date, but the different IDs and StatementIDs

```
ID  |  ResidentID  |  StatementID  |  PostedON
1         4039            10          06-15-18
2         4039            11          06-15-18
3         4039            12          06-15-18

4         4039            20          06-20-18
5         4039            21          06-20-18
6         4039            22          06-20-18

7         3456            13          06-15-18
8         3456            14          06-15-18
9         3456            15          06-15-18

10        3456            23          06-21-18
11        3456            24          06-21-18
```

I have a long list of many ResidentIDs that have duplicates in many dates. How do I delete all rows except the row with the lowest StatementID per unique date for that residentID

I want to delete all duplicates except the smallest StatementID associated with that date/residentID

EDIT:

Actually I can use an update command as there is a soft delete column in this table, but still I can't get it to work. I'm pathetic I know.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed that you need to delete from statemensts not persons
and that StatementNumber is PRIMARY KEY

```
DELETE
FROM
Statements SX
WHERE
SX.StatementNumber IN 
(SELECT s.StatementNumber  
FROM (SELECT *, 
             ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER (
                  PARTITION BY ResidentID, PostedON, PayerTypeID    
                  ORDER BY StatementNumber
                  ) seq
    FROM Statements
    ) s
        INNER JOIN person p ON s.ResidentID = p.ID
WHERE seq > 1
AND p.FacilityID = 275
ORDER BY s.ResidentID)
```

Comment: It's throwing me all kinds of errors with this. StatementNumber is not a primary key, btw

Comment: what errors you got and is StatementID your primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Write the query as:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM (SELECT s.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResidentID, PostedON, PayerTypeID    
                                ORDER BY StatementNumber
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM Statements s
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM person p 
                    WHERE s.ResidentID = p.ID AND p.FacilityID = 275
     ) s
WHERE seq > 1;
```

Voila!  This is an updatable CTE.  You can just delete from it.  I would phrase this as:

```
with todelete as (
          SELECT s.*, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResidentID, PostedON, PayerTypeID    
                                    ORDER BY StatementNumber
                                   ) as seqnum
          FROM Statements s
          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM person p 
                        WHERE s.ResidentID = p.ID AND p.FacilityID = 275
         )
delete todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

You can readily change this to an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
          SELECT s.*, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResidentID, PostedON, PayerTypeID    
                                    ORDER BY StatementNumber
                                   ) as seqnum
          FROM Statements s
          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM person p 
                        WHERE s.ResidentID = p.ID AND p.FacilityID = 275
         )
update toupdate
    set softdelete = 1
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: OMG thank you, so simple. God I have to get better at turning these complex queries into variables. I just get so lost in the formatting.

Comment: @Mr9mm . . . Updatable CTEs/subqueries are a very powerful feature in SQL Server.  It is a shame other databases tend not to support them.